# In Android where to put the global method?

Tags: android

Below is my code to exit my app.

Since I have more than 1 activity, where should I put `exitBy2Click()` so it can be use for all activities?

I tried to create a new class called "Global", and `public exitBy2Click()`, but `Toast.makeText(this,...` not work.

Thanks.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        exitBy2Click(); 
    }
    return false;
}

private static Boolean isExit = false;

private void exitBy2Click() {
    Timer tExit = null;
    if (!isExit) {
        isExit = true; 
        Toast.makeText(this, "click again to quit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        tExit = new Timer();
        tExit.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                isExit = false;
            }
        }, 2000);

    } else {
        finish();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking your method, I think that best option would be Inheritance..

Note on example below that you can override `onBackPressed()` instead of `onKeyDown()`

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    private static Boolean isExit = false;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        exitBy2Click();
    }

    public void exitBy2Click() {
        Timer tExit = null;
        if (!isExit) {
            isExit = true; 
            Toast.makeText(this, "click again to quit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            tExit = new Timer();
            tExit.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    isExit = false;
                }
            }, 2000);

        } else {
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, your "real" activities can extends that `BaseActivity` and this way, `onKeyDown` and `exitBy2Click` will be commom to all classes.

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    }
}

public class SecundaryActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    }
}

//ETC
```

Answer (score 2):

The best place to put this code is literally "nowhere".
Forcibly terminating an Android app is not recommended, and calling System.exit is definitely not something you should ever do in an Android app.